# Android move backward among the records

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I am using cursor to find out max id number then I need to go to 5 backwards of that record. For example, I am in id=9 and I want to go to id=5,How can I do it ? 
I tried

```
int position=cursor.getPosition();  
cursor.moveToPosition(position-5);
```

But, It gives an error

```
 ID  TITLE     FOLDER   PARENT
    1   folder1      1        0
    2   item1        0        1
    3   item2        0        1
    4   folder2      1        1
    5   item1        0        4
    6   item2        0        4
    7   folder3      1        4
    8   item1        0        7
    9   item2        0        7
```

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,title,folder,parent FROM mydata WHERE " +
                     "id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mydata ); ",null);

Comment: Please post the error logcat. If `position - 5` is greater than zero then something else is wrong.

Comment: position always returns 0 even though id=9, and (0-5) returns false value.

Comment: "it gives an error" is meaningless unless you provide the error. We can't see your screen from here; if you don't give us the information, we don't have it to use to try and help you. When you type the word "error", the **very next thing** you should type is the exact error you're getting, including the exact text of any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
cursor.moveToPosition(cursor.getCount() - 5);
```

This assumes you have at least 5 items in the cursor.

**Update**

You are only requesting the details on the row with the highest id.

To get your original request try this query:

```
SELECT id,title,folder,parent FROM mydata
```

With the code suggestion above.

Comment: The size of your cursor is zero? Then your select statement doesn't find any results, start digging there or post it if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,title,folder,parent FROM mydata WHERE " + "id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mydata ); ",null); This is my cursor and the position number is always 0.

Comment: if I use this -> SELECT id,title,folder,parent FROM mydata It goes to first record, I want to opposite

Comment: Now did you try moving the cursor with `cursor.moveToPosition(cursor.getCount() - 5);`? Do you only want to _retrieve_ one row or do you want to _move_ to this row?